# write python inside jquery

Tags: jquery, web2py

I have a [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) application and am using jQuery to validate data. I want to write Python code inside jQuery. How can I do that?

```
if($("#myform_parent_id")[0].value != '' 
    && $("#myform_parent_birthdate")[0].value != ''
    && 
      // Here I want to write Python code
  ..
}
```

Because when i make this code inside controller and then return the form it is reset selected values.

Comment: JavaScript is ran on the client-side, while Python is server-side, so you can't mix them like that.

Comment: Your example is kind of odd. The `&&` seems to indicate you want Python within the JavaScript's `if(..)`, but then the closing `}` does not match.

Comment: Also, you must not rely on jQuery (client-side scripts in general) to validate data. Always validate on the server side; add client-side validation as a service to your visitors. Failure to do so resulted recently in people ordering hundreds of pizzas for one cent each.

Answer (score 1):

If you define this code in the view (instead of the controller) then you can use Python code within {{ }} blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight allows you to embed Python as a scripting language on the client-side. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/silverlight/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

As no browser will understand Python, you'll have to make an Ajax call to the server if you really want to use Python. This will probably complicate things for you, if only as Ajax calls are asynchronous [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). But jQuery [does support it](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).

Alternatively, to keep it all within the browser, you need JavaScript-only. If you can't translate your Python to JavaScript yourself, you could take a look at [automated conversions](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/09/09/19/1345236/Python-Converted-To-JavaScript-Executed-In-Browser).